# MVC identity || Disable all cookies and "remember me" option?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I'm using MVC 4 with identity 2.0 and i have in my site (out of the box feature) "Remember me" and i want to disable this option and have one of this two option in my site:

1.user will need to log in (enter username & password) every time he uses my site.

2.user will need to log in every time **but** the site will remember him for 30 min and not force him to do log-in in that time period(30 min in our situation).

**How can i accomplish those 3 things ?**

to disable i just comment the check box in the login page i think it will do the trick :)

**EDIT:**

When i set this :

```
   app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Logon/LogOn"),
            ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
        });
```

Do i need to comment/delete this code from there:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
                Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
                {
                    OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                        validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                        regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
                }
            });

            app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
```

Comment: This question is quite broad and pertains to things that are very common (and thus well-documented) - what research have you done so far? What have you tried? Where are you struggling?

Comment: i'm struggling in the field of let a user log in to my site but when the user exit the site(close the window and etc) he need to log in again... how can i do it ? the set time of cookies didnt help me much..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For disabling "Remember me" pass `false` as the last parameter in

```
await userManager.SignInAsync(AuthenticationManager, user, false);
```

And remove this checkbox from your view.

To make cookie expire in 30 minutes, in your `Auth.Config` set `ExpireTimeSpan` to 30 minutes

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    LoginPath = new PathString("/Logon/LogOn"),
    ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
});
```

Comment: So if i dont want any cookies at all so the web-app wont remmber any user i just set the expiretimespan to -1 or 0 ?
Thanks for your answers

Comment: and please look at my edit, leave the code there or delete him ?
I think the code just validate so i wont be interrupting..

What you think trialmax ?

Comment: Regarding `expiretimestamp`. If you set it to 0, cookies won't be set at all and your users won't be able to login at all.

Comment: Regarding your edit, you better keep that code and add `app.CreatePerOwinContext(() => new UserManager(new MyDbContext()));` This is a validation of a cookie in case the password was changed. I've blogged about it last week: http://tech.trailmax.info/2014/08/cookieauthenticationprovider-and-user-session-invalidation-on-change-of-securitystamp/

Comment: Nice one thanks, one last question trailmax :
There is anyway to let the user login(without time limit) and when the user get out of the site(log out, exit, close browser) and re-enter the user need to log in again ? i mean keep session with the user not based on time but on connection ?

Comment: No easy way to do that. You might want to set cookie for 3 minutes and have javascript to ping requests back to the server every minute to keep the cookie refreshed while the browser opened. Once it is closed, ajax requests are stopped and cookie is not refreshed => expires in 3 minutes. There was a few questions about it on Stack, but I can't find a good answer just now.

Comment: i didn't think about that approach. Nice! ill investigated it...thanks a lot!

Comment: Well, that's one way of doing it I can think of. Probably there will be other ways, but Identity framework (or any other I know) does not have this inbuilt. So do your research -)